# How to sum values in a range if criteria needs to be of multiple possibilities?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

See screenshot. What I am trying to do is sum up all the fruits distributed by the US, but there are multiple fruits that I need to source from the key. I want to make a dynamic formula instead of summing all individual cells.

I assume I need to use SUMIF, but I haven't been able to make it work appropriately. I tried combining SUMIF with INDEX MATCH to no avail. In the case of the US, since there are two fruits under it, the INDEX MATCH function will only pick up the first fruit and look for it within the table.

[image]

Comment: You can use a helper column (third column after numbers) for country

Comment: You may like to create a helper column that uses VLOOKUP on Key table to fetch the Country/Region in an adjacent column next to Fruits table. Then simple SUMIF shall work well.

Comment: For me, the image link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Key" table, label your "Fruit" column with a unique name. I then created named ranges based on the column headers -- that's not necessary, you can replace with absolute addresses.  My preference would be to use "Tables" with structured references, as they would auto=adjust if you add or subtract lines.

The following array formula must be entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

```
B14:  =SUM(SUMIF(Fruit, IF(Country=A14,KeyFruit,""),Fruits_Picked))
```

The fill down to B16

[image]

Explanation:

- The `IF` function will return an array of the `KeyFruit`  or null strings depending on whether the country matches

  - e.g: `{"Apples","","","Bananas"}`
- That array is then used as the `criteria` argument in the `SUMIF`.
- `SUMIF`, with an array argument for `criteria` will return an array of matching values
- which we then add up with `SUM`